# Trimming off last character if it is a comma SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, if-statement

I have 8 if statements that if a letter is in a field print a word.
And what to do is have a concatenated string of all the options in that field.
Now my problem is how do I put an OR before the last option and take off the comma on the last option.
Here is what I got so

```
    DECLARE @VAR1 VARCHAR(30)
DECLARE @VAR2 VARCHAR(30)
DECLARE @VAR3 VARCHAR(30)
DECLARE @VAR4 VARCHAR(30)
DECLARE @VAR5 VARCHAR(30)
DECLARE @VAR6 VARCHAR(30)
DECLARE @VAR7 VARCHAR(30)
DECLARE @VAR8 VARCHAR(30)
DECLARE @MASTR VARCHAR(90)
DECLARE @PATSTR VARCHAR(30)

SET @VAR1 = ''
SET @VAR2 = ''
SET @VAR3 = ''
SET @VAR4 = ''
SET @VAR5 = ''
SET @VAR6 = ''
SET @VAR7 = ''
SET @VAR8 = ''
SET @MASTR = ''
SET @PATSTR = (SELECT EMAIL FROM CLIENT
                WHERE CLIENT_KEY = 5)
IF @PATSTR LIKE '%a%' PRINT @MASTR + 'Cash, '
ELSE PRINT ''
IF @PATSTR LIKE '%b%' PRINT @MASTR + 'Check, '
ELSE PRINT ''
IF @PATSTR LIKE '%c%' PRINT @MASTR + 'Money Order, '
ELSE PRINT ''
IF @PATSTR LIKE '%d%' PRINT @MASTR + 'Visa, '
ELSE PRINT ''
IF @PATSTR LIKE '%e%' PRINT @MASTR + 'Mastercard, '
ELSE PRINT ''
IF @PATSTR LIKE '%f%' PRINT @MASTR + 'Discover, '
ELSE PRINT ''
IF @PATSTR LIKE '%g%' PRINT @MASTR + 'Amex, '
ELSE PRINT ''
IF @PATSTR LIKE '%h%' PRINT @MASTR + 'Diner Club International, '
ELSE PRINT ''
PRINT @MASTR
```

Comment: At the time when the IF statements are executed, the `@MASTR` variable contains an empty string. So, why then are you printing `@MASTR + 'string'` instead of just `'string'`? Or did you mean to use assignment there instead of printing: `SET @MASTR = @MASTR + '...'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include a case statement to check if @MASTR is blank within each condition check, as following:

```
IF @PATSTR LIKE '%b%'
SET @MASTR = @MASTR
  + CASE WHEN LEN(@MASTR) > 0 THEN ', ' ELSE '' END
  + CASE WHEN @PATSTR LIKE '%b' then 'OR ' ELSE '' END
  + 'Check'
```

Comment: This way you don't have to worry about removing a comma after the last option; you just don't add a comma before each option unless there's already stuff before it.

Comment: I like your suggestion @Adam Miller but for some reason everything is showing up without a comma.

Comment: Which kind of SQL are you using?  LEN(@MASTR) should be returning the length of @MASTR in characters.

Comment: Oh, wait.  I think I see.  I edited my suggestion to change 'PRINT' to 'SET'.  This way, you're embedding them all in @MASTR, and then your print at the end will print the whole string.

Comment: YOU DID IT @ADAM MILLER!! THANKS!! Would there be a way to add an 'or' before the last option?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the 'or'.  Do you mean you only want to show diner club if nothing else was selected?

Comment: If there was a client that had a,b,c right now it would show cash, check, money order. How do I put cash, check or money order? Or if a client has d,e,h how would I print out 'Visa, Mastercard or diners club'? Hope that helps.

Comment: I added another 'case' to my answer that checks if the option was the last in @PATSTR.  It works if they're always going to be in the order that your if statements are in...

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
IF RIGHT(RTRIM(@MASTR),1) = ','
BEGIN
-- Chop off the end character
SET @MASTR = LEFT(@String, LEN(@MASTR) - 1)
END
SELECT @MASTR
```

Comment: You use `rtrim` in your initial `IF` but then only trim the last character. This would work in the case of `my string,` but not `my string,  `

Comment: @Frank V:- I tested it, its working fine with both of the values, are you getting issue?

Comment: @FrankV the reason it will work is related to how SQL Server handles trailing spaces. Try executing: `SELECT LEN('string')` and `SELECT LEN('string                                ')` and you will see that both of them returns the same value..